# How to extract human readable string from a string in ios

Tags: ios7, nsstring

i have a string which is returned by some library, here is a sample response

```
rQ 
First Gulf Bank ﬁéj
=5’. ﬁalﬁps
5; L mu nrslgk-5. §
. s,,,.Ef.<   W3 ‘
zi‘ ‘ im?“%‘.‘ ;
k :LII__1';&g§;J_E1> J
```

now from the above response how can i extract human readable text, for ex, First Gulf Bank in the above sample, any sdk?

Comment: It's clearly not a string; it just happens to have string fragments within it.  What is the object returned by this library (please post a link to the library/method used)?

Comment: i was trying to use tesract to detect text from an image        Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];
    [tesseract setVariableValue:@"language_model_penalty_non_dict_word" forKey:@"0"];
    [tesseract setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"City-credit-card.jpg"]];
    [tesseract recognize];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);                https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios